# Java synchronized overwriting value

Tags: java, multithreading, download, race-condition

I'm programming a multiple file downloader in Java with JavaFx, but i have some problems with threading.
The problem i have is with the threading part.
I want to start multiple downloads (different urls / files) at the same time, for example two. If i start this two downloadthreads (I think) a race condition happens, because the filename and filesize for both threads are the same and there is also only one file on the HDD, not two as expected.
I am sure it's a race condition problem, but how can i solve it?

Main.java

```
package de.minimal.program;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

import de.minimal.program.model.Download;
import de.minimal.program.util.Dl;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

private ObservableList<Download> downloadData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private int i = 0;

public ObservableList<Download> getDownloadData(){
    return downloadData;
}


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    downloadData.add(new Download("http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/videolan/vlc/2.2.1/win32/vlc-2.2.1-win32.exe"));
    downloadData.add(new Download("http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso"));

    ArrayList<Thread> t = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2, new ThreadFactory() {
          @Override
          public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
              Thread a = new Thread(r);
              a.setName("Thread " + i);
              i++;
              t.add(a);
              return a;
          }
        });

    for(Download dl : downloadData){
        Dl d = new Dl(dl);
        executor.execute(d);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

DL.java

```
package de.minimal.program.util;

import java.util.List;

import de.minimal.program.httpconnection.HttpConnection;
import de.minimal.program.model.Download;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class Dl extends Task<List<Download>> implements Runnable{

private Download download;
private HttpConnection connection;

public Dl(Download download){
    this.download = download;

}

@Override
protected synchronized List<Download> call() throws Exception {
    connection = new HttpConnection(download);
    connection.downloadFile();
    return null;
}
}
```

HTTPConnection.java

```
package de.minimal.program.httpconnection;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import de.minimal.program.model.Download;

    public class HttpConnection {

    private static String url;
    private Download download;

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    public HttpConnection(Download download){
    this.download = download;
    }

    public void downloadFile() throws IOException{

    String saveDir = download.getDownloadSavePath();

    url = download.getDownloadUrl();
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    // Forbid redirects for file resuming reasons
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

    // always check HTTP response code first
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK || responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_PARTIAL) {
        String fileName = "";
        String disposition = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
        long contentLength = connection.getContentLengthLong();

        boolean appendToFile = false;
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_PARTIAL)
            appendToFile = true;

        if(download.getFilesize() == 0){
            download.setFilesize(contentLength);
        }

        if (disposition != null) {
            // extracts file name from header field
            int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
            if (index > 0) {
                fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                disposition.length() - 1);
            }
        } else {
            // extracts file name from URL
            fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.length());
         }

        download.setFilename(fileName);

        // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

        // opens an output stream to save into file
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath, appendToFile);

        int bytesRead = -1;
        long downloadedBytes = download.getTransferedBytes();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            downloadedBytes += bytesRead;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - start >= 2000){

                download.setTransferedBytes(downloadedBytes);
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } 
        }

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Filedownload " + fileName + " finished");

    } else {
        System.out.println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: " + responseCode);
    }
    connection.disconnect();
}
}
```

Download.java

```
package de.minimal.program.model;

import javafx.beans.property.LongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Download {

private final StringProperty filename;
private final StringProperty filepath;
private final LongProperty filesize;
private final LongProperty transferedBytes;
private String downloadUrl;
private String downloadSavePath = "SET PATH ";

public Download(){
    this("");
}

public Download(String downloadUrl){
    this.downloadUrl = downloadUrl;
    this.filename = new SimpleStringProperty(downloadUrl);
    this.filepath = new SimpleStringProperty(downloadSavePath);
    this.filesize = new SimpleLongProperty(0);
    this.transferedBytes = new SimpleLongProperty(0);
}

// Filename
public synchronized String getFilename(){
    return filename.get();
}

public synchronized void setFilename(String filename){
    System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Set filename: " + filename);
    this.filename.set(filename);
}

public synchronized StringProperty filenameProperty(){
    return filename;
}

// Filepath
public String getFilepath(){
    return filepath.get();
}

public void setFilepath(String filepath){
    System.out.println("Set filepath: " + filepath);
    this.filepath.set(filepath);
}

public StringProperty filepathProperty(){
    return filepath;
}

// Filesize
public Long getFilesize(){
    return filesize.get();
}

public void setFilesize(Long filesize){
    System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Set filesize: " + filesize);
    this.filesize.set(filesize);
}

public LongProperty filesizeProperty(){
    return filesize;
}

// TransferedBytes
public Long getTransferedBytes(){
    return transferedBytes.get();
}

public void setTransferedBytes(Long transferedBytes){
    System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " bytes transfered " + transferedBytes);
    this.transferedBytes.set(transferedBytes);
}

public LongProperty transferedBytesProperty(){
    return transferedBytes;
}

// URL
public String getDownloadUrl(){
    return downloadUrl;
}

public void setDownloadUrl(String downloadUrl){
    this.downloadUrl = downloadUrl;
}

// SavePath
public String getDownloadSavePath(){
    return downloadSavePath;
}

public void setDownloadSavePath(String downloadSavePath){
    this.downloadSavePath = downloadSavePath;
}
}
```

EDIT:
<s>This is the minimal code.

You can add links, start and stop downloads, and change the number of simultaneous concurrent downloads.</s>

EDIT 2:
Minified it again. Hope this time its better.
Adds two downloadlinks and starts them immediately. Reproduces the mentioned problem.

EDIT 3:
Solved it.
The problem was the 
    private static String url; 
I remember that my professor told once that static variables are not thread safe. So more information can found here
[10 points about Static in Java](http://java67.blogspot.de/2012/11/what-is-static-class-variable-method.html)  point 2

Comment: This is not complete code, and I think you have picked the wrong parts of the code to show. Your synchronization seems to be meaningless as each `Runnable` synchronizes on itself, but I don't think the problem is there. Please create a [mcve], cutting away all the unnecessary code, to enable us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Edited it, now its a minimal, complete and functional example.
It's just adding, starting, downloading and possibility to stop the downloads.

Comment: That's far from being minimal. Minimal means keeping only the parts of the code that are needed to demonstrate the problem. Why is it necessary to add links, stop downloads and change the numbers? It is not supposed to be *flexible*. It's supposed to run a simple demonstration of the problem, regardless of user input. And then explain what the program does when you start it, and what it should do instead.

Comment: I minified it again. No GUI, only command line output. Wouldn't know how to minify more.

Answer (score 1):

Is writing in a single file a real constraint ? What you could do is to write in separate files, then once the files are complete, merge them into a single one.

Alternatively, if the results from the requests are not so big and could fit in memory, you could directly return the files from the downloading threads, and then write them into a single file.

Comment: They are different files, for example one download is a ubuntu file and the second is a debian file. So there cannot be merged anything

Comment: I think I am missing something. Don't you have to download multiple files at the same time and write it in a single file ? I was just stating that instead of each thread writing in this unique file, each thread could write into a separate file, and then take the content of the two files to merge it into a single one. This would solve your concurrency issue.

Comment: No each thread is processing its own file. Thread 1 is downloading a file from server a, Thread 2 is downloading a file from server b, Thread 3 from server c and so on.

Comment: I am sorry, but could you explain me what bother you in my approach of writing the results in separate files and after all the downloads are complete, re-merge them into one file ?

Comment: They are different files. For example if Thread 1 downloads the VLC Media Player and Thread 2 downloads an Ubuntu Image, why should i merge them? The new file that would would be useless. I don't want to have more than one connection for a filedownload at the moment (no chunkloading), I just want to download __different__ files parallel.